# html type="number" : Show always 2 digits after dot?

Tags: html, numbers

in a `type="number"` input, i would like to show 2 digits after dot like "2.50"

if a try

```
<input name="price" type="number" step="0.01" value="2.5">
```

this show me "2.5" and not "2.50"

Have you a method to do this ? HTML5 pure or with javascript ?

Comment: <input name="price" type="number" step="0.01" value="2.50">

Comment: if you satisying with my answer then vote up so that other people can find easily

Answer (score 0):

You can solve by script Like :

```
<script type="text/javascript">      
  $(document).ready(function() {
  var num = 2.5;
  var n = num.toFixed(2);
  alert(n);
  });    
</script>    
<script type="text/javascript">      
  $(document).ready(function() {
  var num = 2.500;
  var n = num.toFixed(1);
  alert(n);
  });    
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use Jquery or JavaScript for that what ever you want but this solution in Jquery

You Can't go for more than 2 number

```js
//Use keyup to capture user input & mouse up to catch when user is changing the value with the arrows
    $('.trailing-decimal-input').on('keyup mouseup', function (e) {

        // on keyup check for backspace & delete, to allow user to clear the input as required
        var key = e.keyCode || e.charCode;
        if (key == 8 || key == 46) {
            return false;
        };

        // get the current input value
        let correctValue = $(this).val().toString();

         //if there is no decimal places add trailing zeros
        if (correctValue.indexOf('.') === -1) {
            correctValue += '.00';
        }

        else {

            //if there is only one number after the decimal add a trailing zero
            if (correctValue.toString().split(".")[1].length === 1) {
                correctValue += '0'
            }

            //if there is more than 2 decimal places round backdown to 2
            if (correctValue.toString().split(".")[1].length > 2) {
                correctValue = parseFloat($(this).val()).toFixed(2).toString();
            }
        }

        //update the value of the input with our conditions
        $(this).val(correctValue);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="my-number-input" class="form-control trailing-decimal-input" type="number" min="0.01" step="0.01" value="2.50" />
```

you can preview or edit code [Here on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zysvu6jm/)

Comment: thanks Kiran. your solution works in chrome if i lunch it on jsfiddle (or "run code snippet" here). but not in firefox :/